# Varying magnetic field, and a larger area?

Tags: electromagnetism

Considering this classical example:
[image]
The magnetic flux($\phi$) is increasing over some time(increase in $B$), and it's simple to indicate the direction of the induced current using Lenz law.

However, the magnetic field is only in a specific region, what if the magnetic field would increase, covering a larger area?

[image]

I can't find a current flow(pattern) for the loop that would resist the change,nor explain why that is.

Comment: The magnetic field outside the loop has no effect on the EMF in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conducting metal coil in a varying magnetic field opposes the change in magnetic flux through it. This opposition induces a current in the loop, the direction of which can be found out by Lenz's Law.

Now we know that magnetic flux is given by $$\phi_B = \int B.dA$$ which is the  summation of the scalar products of the  magnetic field and the differential area elements enclosed. Now, as said earlier, the induced current is generated by the opposing  the change in flux and as the flux is calculated keeping in mind the area enclosed by the coil only and not its surroundings so we will not consider the larger area but only the area enclosed by the loop.

So as the change in magnetic field outside the loop does not affect current induced due to change in flux of the loop so in this case too the current will flow in anti clockwise direction and will have the same magnitude as in the first case, as illustrated below. [image: The pic]

Comment: But what if we did consider the surroudings and the enclosed reigion? How will things change.

Comment: As I've said earlier we won't consider the surrounding area as it is not responsible for changing the flux through the coil. So in your second case also the direction of the current will be anti clockwise.

Comment: I have edited the answer for clarity.